# Data-bind dynamically named data-* attributes with attr binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've found a couple of similar questions, but none of them seem to address this issue exactly.

I'm trying to add attributes to an element based on a list of 'tags'. Each tag is a part of a group.  The group will be the attribute name, and the tags will all be in the values.

Basically, I want to execute something similar to this:

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: Options">
  <li>
    <a href="#" 
       data-bind="text: $data, 
                  attr: { 'data-' + $parent.Name : $data, 
                          'data-multiselect': $parent.IsMultiSelect.toString(), 
                          'rel': $parent.Name }">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The important part of the code is `attr: { 'data-' + $parent.Name : $data`...

I've tried various methods of making this work such as determining the attribute names up front, computing them, calling functions, etc., but knockout just will not process them.

Comment: Useless even　`'data-' + $parent.Name()` ?

Comment: that doesn't work out

Comment: How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/t5m0edz1/

Comment: unless they are in template

Comment: After some puzzling I understand what you're getting at. I've attempted to rewrite your title so it better reflects the question imho. Please do roll back my change if you feel it changed the meaning too much and/or if it was incorrect.

Comment: looks fine Jeroen, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a custom binding would be in order here. Like this:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.customDataAttr = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var key = valueAccessor().name;
      var val = valueAccessor().val;
      element.setAttribute(key, val);
      
      // see that it's been set:
      console.log(element);
    }
};

var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.Options = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  self.Name = ko.observable("my-name");
  self.IsMultiSelect = 'false';
  
  self.dataAttrName = ko.computed(function(){
    return 'data-' + self.Name();
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: Options">
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="x"
       data-bind="text: $data, 
                  customDataAttr: { val: $data, name: $parent.dataAttrName() },
                  attr: { 'data-multiselect': $parent.IsMultiSelect.toString(), 
                          'rel': $parent.Name }">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: whoa, what is this run code snippet stuff, first time I've seen it, very cool

Comment: @RobA [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/419956), you can use 'm in questions too: it's one of the buttons on the editor's toolbar. Adding them as a repro in a question will surely get you quicker / better answers relatively.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a function that build the object with the dynamic properties:

```
self.createTagAttribute = function(tag, value) {
    var attrs = {};
    attrs[tag] = value;
    return attrs;
};
```

And in your binding:

```
<li><a href="#" data-bind="
    text: $data, 
    attr: ko.utils.extend(
        $root.createTagAttribute($parent.Name, $data), 
        {'data-multiselect': $parent.IsMultiSelect.toString(), 'rel': $parent.Name}
    )"></a></li>
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your binding clean (and you feel morally okay extending the Object prototype), you could add the following:

```
Object.prototype.add = function(key, value) {
    this[key] = value;
    return this;
};
```

*(This should be placed before `ko.applyBindings`)*

After this you can do the following:

```
<a href="#" 
   data-bind="text: $data, 
              attr: { 'data-multiselect': $parent.IsMultiSelect.toString(), 
                      'rel': $parent.Name }.add('data-' + $parent.Name, $data)">
```